# How to run qiskit circuit in the cloud - qiskit runtime

Tags: qiskit, qiskit-runtime

Last night I created an IBM Cloud account. I can run the "sampler':

```
with Sampler(circuits=qc, service=service, options={"backend": ""}) as sampler:
            result=sampler(circuit_indices=[0], shots=1024)
            print(result)
```

The results are printed. However, I want to display a histogram of my execution results (just like I do with regular qiskit) and I don't know how to do that.

For example, there is no "result.get_counts()"

Answer (score 1):

Qiskit Runtime `Sampler` returns an instance of [`SamplerResult`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.primitives.SamplerResult.html). You can use its `quasi_dists` attribute to get the list of the quasi-probabilities then pass it to `plot_histogram` function:

```
plot_histogram(result.quasi_dists)
```